# Variational Problem.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

How to solve variational problem $$I(y)=\int_0^1 [(y’)^2-y|y|y’+xy]dx,y(0)=y(1)=0?$$

I tried by Euler equation, which is $$ -2|y|y’+x-\frac{d}{dx}(2y’-y|y|)=0$$ Now stuck. Unable to creat corresponding differential equation. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(y|y|)&=\frac{d}{dx}
\begin{cases}
y^2&\text{if $y\geq 0$,} \\
-y^2&\text{if $y<0$,}
\end{cases} \\
&=\begin{cases}
2yy'&\text{if $y\geq 0$,} \\
-2yy'&\text{if $y<0$,}
\end{cases} \\
&=2|y|y', \tag{1}
\end{align}
hence
$$
-2|y|y’+x-\frac{d}{dx}(2y’-y|y|)=0 \implies x-2y''=0. \tag{2}
$$